# How to Store Each date Records in Array laravel

Tags: php, laravel

```
$gno =head::select('point')->where('DATE', '>', Carbon::now()->subDays(7))-> orderBy('DATE','desc')->get();

return $gno;
```

Above code returns past seven days record from point column and i counted this
using Below code

```
 $gcs=$gno->count();
  $gccount=explode(', ', $gcs);
  return $gccount;
```

Its returns ["36"]  count as  seven days Records
but  I Expected :
I want To store each date record count as array Example like
["5","15","20","12","4","2","4"]  count as starting from today i think this will done by  use loops
But i dont know hoe to fix it??Thanks

Comment: Do you want the data date-wise? Right?

Comment: yes  from today  to past days

Comment: Then simply group by date and count.

Comment: I dont know how to do?

Comment: check the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have to read the [Laravel collection methods](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections) which help here to get the data date-wise.

We first get the basic data with the order by clause.

Then the database collection return by query, we can use the collection' [groupBy, map, values, and implode](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#available-methods) function to get the appropriate data.

```
$gno = head::select('point', 'DATE')->where('DATE', '>', Carbon::now()->subDays(7))->orderBy('DATE','desc')->get();
$gnoByCount = $gno->groupBy('DATE')->map(function($g) {
    return $g->count();
})->values()->implode(',');

var_dump($gnoByCount);
```

Comment: i want  to  return count of record  against date in chart

Comment: your answer returns sum of count for  saven days but i want to print  seven days record counts in array For Example  ["5","15","20","12","4","2","4"]

Comment: No, it will return the array where each element return the number of records for that particular date.

Comment: Just remote this `->values()->implode(',');` and confirm the records are coming date wise and key will be the date.

Comment: It is `var_dump` not `var_dumb`

Comment: its returns string(2) "36"

Comment: It means you can only have one record I guess in the last 7 days

Comment: and also try by add "DATE" in the select function. Check updated answer.

Comment: after adding this worked  saved me thanks

Comment: If the searching date not found  i want to return 0

Comment: You should not extend this question anymore. Because community may not read all comments. So Post another question

Answer (score 2):

If you just want an array of the `points`, then you can use [`pluck`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-pluck):

```php
$gno = head::select('point')
        ->where('DATE', '>', Carbon::now()->subDays(7))
        ->orderBy('DATE','desc')
        ->get();

$gno->pluck('points')->toArray();
```